# Vectors in 3D at Arbitrary Locations

Tags: vector

I have a dataset of coordinates that describe the origins (x0, y0, z0) and the end-points (x1, y1, z1) of corresponding vectors. Each record is of the form {{x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1}...}. How are these best defined under Mathematica as vectors such that they may be operated on and plotted? Running under Mathematica version 11.1.1.0.

Comment: `Graphics3D[Arrow/@Partition[#,3]&/@data]`?

Comment: try `Graphics3D[Arrow[Partition[#, 3] & /@ data]]`

Comment: The operation @Partition[#,3]&/@data correctly partitioned records, however, the process is incomplete.

Comment: Please post the  data and give a working example.

Comment: The data was retrieved from a '.CSV' file from which text, control characters and null records were removed during reading. I did not realise that Mathematica didn't recognise the remaining numeric values as Real and so all subsequent operations, including the answer given here, failed.

Comment: Opening the .CSV file in Mac OS Numbers and exporting it back to a .CSV file corrected all issues and values were immediately recognised by Mathematica as Reals. The solution below performed as displayed. All necessary operations that I need to perform are now possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[1, {10, 6}];
```

You can [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) 6-tuples into a pair of triples and use [`Arrow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow.html):

```
Graphics3D[{RandomColor[], Arrow @#} & /@ (Partition[#, 3] & /@ data)]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`ArrayReshape`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html):

```
Partition[#, 3] & /@ data == ArrayReshape[data, {Length@data, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

You can use `Arrow @* Tube` to get fancier-looking arrows:

```
Graphics3D[{RandomColor[], Arrowheads[.07], CapForm["Butt"], 
    Arrow[Tube[#, .01], -.05]} & /@ (Partition[#, 3] & /@ data)]
```

[image]